# is there way to post moment (date & time) with Axios? concatenate variable "startDateStr" to the https

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios, expo

is there a way to post moment (date & time) with Axios? 
I mean concatenate variable "startDateStr" to the https
this is how I try to do it with "**startDateStr**" but it's not work for me.
whats wrong with my way?

```
postData = () => {
        const startDateStr = encodeURI(moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'))
        const axios = require('axios')
        axios.post('https://harigotphat1.mekorot.co.il/ConfirmPackaotWS/api/RW/WriteLog/'+startDateStr,{
             })
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            })
    }
componentDidMount() {
        this.postData()
    }
```

Comment: What's an error? Is it should be a part of url? Or a request payload?

Comment: yes, i want it will be a part of URL.
if i put just text (BIGBAN) on the end of the url so it works and i see my post :
axios.post('https://harigotphat1.mekorot.co.il/ConfirmPackaotWS/api/RW/WriteLog/BIGBAN',{
        })
/////////////////////////
but if i put my above example so its not work !

Comment: What errors did you get?

Comment: You need to import Axios outside of component. Like `import axios from 'axios';`

Comment: error 400 -request failed with status code 400

Comment: i did already import axios from 'axios'

Comment: 400 means bad request. I think you need to double check your API request url

Comment: You have formatted date with spaces and seems like API doesn't accept it

Comment: if i put just text (BIGBAN) on the end of the url so it works and i see my post : axios.post('harigotphat1.mekorot.co.il/ConfirmPackaotWS/api/RW/WriteLog/BIGBAN',{ })   
so its work ..

Comment: urlencode this string

Comment: how do i formate it ? how should i write ?

Comment: `encodeURI(moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'))`

Comment: someone can show me please what to do ? it confuses

Comment: i did the encodeURI , but get the same error

Comment: check API specs

Comment: i want put the "startDateStr" as a string inside the post like this : 
axios.post('https://harigotphat1.mekorot.co.il/ConfirmPackaotWS/api/RW/WriteLog/startDateStr',{
        })

Comment: `encodeURI` should work, check api (accepts any string?) with `.../WriteLog/some%20spaces`

Comment: @ xadm - its should be as my edit example above now ?

Comment: if not working check api with postman